# About the IAM role in cdk bootstrap

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

The following IAM roles were found in the bootstrap of cdk.

- FilePublishingRole
- ImagePublishingRole
- LookupRole
- DeploymentActionRole
- CloudFormationExecutionRole

I understand the meaning of CloudFormationExecutionRole, but in what situations are the other IAM roles used? I would like to know if there is any documentation that clearly states this.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about the roles?

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand the role now. By the way, I experimented and confirmed that the CDK works as long as I have CloudFormationExecutionRole.

Answer (score 4):

The roles are defined [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-cdk/master/packages/aws-cdk/lib/api/bootstrap/bootstrap-template.yaml). Looking at the definitions you can see what they are used for:

- FilePublishingRole - access to S3 with associated KMS
- ImagePublishingRole - access to ECR
- LookupRole - role to performe lookups with various `fromLookup` methods
- DeploymentActionRole - access to CloudFormation, KMS and S3

Comment: The LookupRole is used when performing lookups (with various `fromLookup` methods in the CDK), not just to deny `kms:Decrypt`.

Comment: @gshpychka Thanks, I will update the answer.

Comment: You can also run `cdk bootstrap --show-template > bootstrap-template.yaml` using the CDK CLI to get the bootstrap cloud formation template.

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html#bootstrapping-contract-roles):

- FilePublishingRole, ImagePublishingRole - are assumed by the AWS CDK Toolkit and by AWS CodeBuild projects to publish assets into an environment: that is, to write to the S3 bucket and the ECR repository, respectively. These roles require write access to these resources.
- LookupRole - is assumed by the AWS CDK Toolkit to perform context lookups in an environment. Its AssumeRolePolicy controls who can deploy into the environment.
- DeploymentActionRole - is assumed by the AWS CDK Toolkit and by AWS CodePipeline to deploy into an environment. Its AssumeRolePolicy controls who can deploy into the environment.